# Country support for Ingress

Tags: ingress

I noticed that ingress is real world game. However all pictures show what appears to be USA area's. However I wonder if it supports maps from outside the US also.

I've tried to find some info about this but its nowhere to be found.

What countries are supported by Ingress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately the app and all the online material are only available in English, but you can play the game anywhere in the world where there are portals. I play in Berlin, Germany and we have more than a thousand portals and more than 600 players here.

So if you are able to understand the English app and online material, you can play it in any country. In Berlin we also have a very active Google+ community in which we speak German. So even if you are not fluent in English, you should be able to play the game, if you know the few terms you find in the game.

Comment: btw: even without an account, you can see the current map on this page: http://maps.ingressworld.it/

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a reference to the exact list of supported countries, but that may be because there isn't one.  Certain places in the world have restricted internet, so in those places the game may not be supported, but in general I believe you can play the game anywhere - and this is made easier by being able to [submit new portals](http://support.google.com/ingress/answer/2808254?hl=en) yourself, which you can subsequently control.

There are a series of maps [here](http://ingressportal.com/maps/#), some of which you can only see if you have a game account, but they seem to imply global support.  The group directory [here](http://ingressportal.com/directory/) also has links for every inhabited continent, which further supports this hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that Netherlands is pretty crowded, so i should enjoy a lot of fun there. :)

Answer (score 1):

Many countries have players - it is supposed to be global, barring the restrictions @EBongo mentioned.

The official intel site at [Ingress.com/intel](http://www.ingress.com/intel) has a global map which shows all portals and fields. At widest view you just see lvl 8 portals, but as you zoom in you see lower level ones.

If you zoom in to the Netherlands you can see while there are only a handful of lvl 8 portals, there are loads of smaller ones so lots of good hacking to be had.

Comment: You can only view the intel map if you've got an invite.

Comment: currently requesting an invite seems to take about 10 days - which isn't bad